# OpenVPN: Run 'bridge-start' on boot before starting openvpn service (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn, bridge, ubuntu-12.10

I've got OpenVPN working properly on my server, using [bridge-start and bridge-stop scripts](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html) to create and remove network bridge, respectively.

How do I set these scripts up to run bridge-start at boot before starting OpenVPN, and bridge-stop at shutdown after stopping OpenVPN? I've tried adding `up "/path/to/bridge-start"` and `down "/path/to/bridge-stop"` to `server.conf` but the bridge interface doesn't get created.  It appears these scripts absolutely have to be run separate from OpenVPN's own startup/shutdown.